# Can I make a final RRSP contribution after moving to the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, contribution, rrsp

I moved from Canada to the U.S. (California) in August 2013. I am wondering whether I can make one final contribution to my RRSP account for the 2013 tax year (transferring between Canadian accounts) to max out my RRSPs for 2013? I lived and worked in Canada for all my life until August 2013. I do not plan on touching these accounts again after this until I retire.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late now but the answer to this is yes you can still purchase RRSPs for a tax year in which you were a resident and earned income even if you are not presently a resident.

http://www.afbs.ca/public/index.php/staticpage/index/page/346/mapid/425

As a side note if you have significant assets in your RRSPs you may still be a resident as far as CRA is concerned.  The rules around non-residency are fuzzy but one of the key points is that holding significant assets in Canada makes you a resident regardless of where you live.